# What is the derivative of potential energy with respect to $x$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, potential-energy, conservative-field

I was reading an article which was proving the conservation of energy with calculus, but they did not explain why the derivative of potential energy with respect to $x$ is the negative force.

$${dU\over dx} = -F(x) .$$

If someone could explain the reasoning behind why there is a negative in the derivative, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Another current question on this theme: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/732182/123208

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is work defined as force dot displacement?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37829/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the derivative and then with the minus sign.

Consider a function $ f(x) $ which can be written as the derivative of some other function u(x), i.e,

$$ f(x) = \frac{du}{dx} $$

Then we now from calculus that the path integral between from point A to point B is given by

$$ \int_A^B f(x) dx = \int_A^B \frac{du}{dx}dx = u(B) - u(A) $$

In this case, since we're working in 1 dimension, A and B would correspond to real numbers.

**Now to the Physics.**

The infinitesimal work done by a force, $F(x)$, is given as

$$ dW = F(x) dx $$

which means

$$ W = \int_A^B F(x) dx $$

A ***convervative*** force is such that the work does not depend on the path. As we have seen from above, this is true when

$$ F = -\frac{dU}{dx}. $$

Here the minus sign is a convention which will be clear in a moment.

The work is then given by

$$ \int_A^B F(x) dx = - \left[ U(B) - U(A) \right] $$

Now, how can we identify $U(x)$ as the pontential energy? From the work-energy theorem (which is proven here: [Why is work defined as force dot displacement?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/why-is-work-defined-as-force-dot-displacement)) we have

$$ W = \Delta K $$

where $K$ is the potential energy. Since the force, $F(x)$ is conservative, the mecanical energy,

$$E_M = K + U_p$$

where $U_p$ is the potential energy of the system (which we'll show equals $U(x)$) is conserved, i.e., $\Delta E_M = 0$. Thus,

$$ \Delta K = -\Delta U_p $$

But as seen from above $W = -(U(B) - U(A)) = -\Delta U $, therefore we can identify

$$ \boxed{U_p = U(x)} $$

Without the **minus sign** we would have $ U_p = -U(x) $ which is why it is introduced earlier.

**Note:** Always remember that this is only valid for conservative forces. Even though in nature every force is in fact conservative, one often deals with non-conservative forces due to approximations (example: air resistance, friction, etc.)